# Ajax or loading a fragment of page does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

I currently have a problem with ajax or loading a fragment of page with $('#id').load("page.php #id").
What I'm trying to do is an image gallery. 
To allow the user to update the name of an album, I created a form with a button calling an ajax function. This ajax function sends the datas in post like "$_POST['oldAlbumName'] = 'newAlbumName'" (more or less).
Unfortunately, nothing happens.

I don't know if it comes from the ajax or from the reloading of the span.
Here is my PHP :

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT album AS A from galerie');
    while($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {
        echo $donnees['A']."<br/>";
        if(isset($_POST[$donnees['A']."_text"]))
        {
            echo $_POST[$donnees['A']."_text"]."<br/>";
            echo $donnees['A']."_text<br/>";
            $bdd->query("UPDATE galerie SET album ='".$_POST[$donnees['A']."_text"]."' WHERE album='".$donnees['A']."_text'");
        }
    }
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Impossible de se connecter à la BDD<br/>";
}?>
```

(The echo only prints "Rouge", which is normal)

And here is my JS :

```
    function renommageAjax(textID)
    {
        var splitted = textID.split("_");
        var champ = splitted[0];
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Galerie.php",
          data: {
            textID: $("#"+textID).val(),
          },
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(data) {
            alert(textID);  
            $('#'+champ+'_name').html($("#"+textID).val());
            $('#updateSpan').load("Galerie.php #updateSpan");

          }
         });        
    }
```

(The alert prints "Rouge_text" in my case, wich is also normal)

Of course, my php is between two spans with the ID "updateSpan", in the page "Galerie.php".

Where is/are my error(s) ?

Thank you !

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific than "nothing happens". And the ajax statement you provided sends `textID`, not `oldAlbumName`.

Comment: By nothings happens, I mean that my database is not updated. About the "oldAlbumName", It was to explain what I wanted to do.
Shouldn't I try to get a $_POST['textID'] instead of a $_POST['Rouge_text'] here ?

Comment: Also, we never go inside the  if(isset($_POST[$donnees['A']."_text"])) ... I don't see why.

Comment: If you're sending the value under the name `textID`, of course that's what you should use in your PHP.

Comment: In the javascript function, textID is a String transmitted from the button, and the value of textID is "Rouge_text" (in the case I test).
Anyway, I tried a if(isset($_POST['textID'])) but i still dont enter this condition.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you're expecting the textID property name in your object literal to evaluate based on its value, that won't happen. The only way to achieve that is like this: `var obj = {}; obj[textID] = $("#"+textID).val()`. You also have a trailing comma in there you should get rid of.

Comment: I don't really understand what I should do with the var obj ... 
I mean, how do I use it in the js ? I'm not very familiar with JS. And how do I get the data in the PHP ?

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL injection. Using PDO is not enough, you need to use prepared statements too

Comment: Apart from that, Josh is right. You are sending the parameter "textID" but then trying to read the parameter "oldAlbumName_text" (using your example above). Notice that you would need to change it not only on the `if`, but also inside it

Comment: I tried to print all the datas in POST but it seems that nothing is sent from the ajax. Also, I don't know how to use the 'var obj={}' in my js as well as in my php, since it seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Josh, I figured out how to solve my problem :

I changed my JS (so my php too) so I send two values : the old one and the new one.

The new PHP looks like this :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['textOld']))
{
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT album AS A from galerie');

        while($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
        {

            if($_POST['textOld'] == $donnees['A'])
            {
                $bdd->query("UPDATE galerie SET album ='".$_POST['textNew']."' WHERE album='".$_POST['textOld']."'");
            }   

        }

        $reponse->closeCursor();
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Impossible de se connecter à la BDD<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

And the new JS :

```
function renommageAjax(textID)
{
var splitted = textID.split("_");
var champ = splitted[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Galerie.php",
        data: {
            textOld: champ,
            textNew:  $("#"+textID).val()
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {   
            $('#'+champ+'_name').html($("#"+textID).val());
            $('#updateSpan').load("Galerie.php #updateSpan");

        }
    });
}
```